# Limiting the number of users

Tags: users, limit

I was wondering if there is a way to actually *limit* the amount of users that can register to a Wordpress site?

As an example, I am wanting to create a small site that will hold information for a customer, where they can only have a maximum of (for example) 50 users. The idea is that you will need to log in to view the site and only a set amount of users are allowed to be created. Maybe somebody knows of a plugin that might do this?

Comment: Craig, any progress on that question?

Comment: At the moment, the site we're developing is still in it's smaller stages, this will probably come later on and so I haven't been able to try it out just yet. However, it was important to know that this was possible.

Comment: Please always add comments/feedback to the answers. If you got a solution that works, come back and mark it as such, etc. Else the question stays in the queue of unanswered questions forever.

Comment: Ahh ok. I have accepted your answer, as so it doesn't go unanswered. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Sorry, Craig. I didn't meant "go accept". I meant: for the future please always go and comment. And if you have tried it and can confirm that it's working, then please mark _the working_ answer as solution. Until then it's ok to leave it open, just come back and don't forget about it :) - you can just uncheck it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [WordPress Option Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference), there's an option called `users_can_register`. You can - per default - set it in your (network-)sites settings.

- `1` => Yes
- `0` => No

As usual: There's a filter to intercept that from a plugin.

```
"option_{$option_name}"
```

So you can simply attach a callback to this filter and check the amount of users with a [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) for the [`get_current_blog_id()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_current_blog_id/).

```
<?php

namespace WPSE;
/** Plugin Name: WPSE (#110036) Limit Total Users per page */
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;

\add_filter( 'option_users_can_register', 'limit_total_users' );
function limit_total_users( $option )
{
    // Nothing to do here
    if ( 0 === $option )
        return $option;

    static $users = null;
    $limit = 50;

    if ( null === $users )
    {
        $users_query = new \WP_User_Query( array(
            'blog_id' => get_current_blog_id()
        ) );
        $users = $users_query->get_total();
    }

    // Abort if we're above the limit
    if ( $limit > $users )
        return 0;

    return $option;
}
```

The nice thing about this mini plugin is, that it doesn't do an additional query if the registration is already turned off.

Comment: Good answer Kaiser, but this method will more easily return the number of users: [Function Reference/count users « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_users)

Comment: @GhostToast Are you [sure about that](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6/wp-includes/user.php#L873)? Anyway, just clone my answer, change that bits and add it as your own.

Comment: Thank you for this comment Kaiser, I'll make sure to try this out when we get something up and running!

Answer (score 3):

Piggybacking off Kaiser's answer:

```
add_filter( 'option_users_can_register', 'limit_total_users' );
function limit_total_users( $option )
{
    // Registration turned off manually. Nothing to do here.
    if ( 0 === $option )
        return $option;

    $user_count = count_users();

    // Abort if we're above the limit
    if ( $user_count['total_users'] > 50 ) {
        return 0;
    } 

    // The threshold wasn't reached yet.
    return $option;
}
```

Interesting bit of info on that `count_users()` function is it actually returns an array with a count for each role. You may wish to identify which role you are limiting, or simply add/subtract to account for the difference in, for example, the number of admins - as you may not wish to count yourself in the total.

Answer (score 2):

This solution differs from the others in that the primary work in done on user registration. After a user registers the total users are counted and the `users_can_register` option is updated if necessary. That seems to be the best way to minimize front-end processing time. A related function hooked to `pre_option_users_can_register` prevents blog admins from cheating by toggling the switch in "General Settings" and getting an extra user thereby. Technically only that function is necessary but I have explained the reasons for the other function.

```
function count_reg_users_wpse_110036() {
  global $wpdb;
  $users = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->users}");
  return $users;
}

function limit_users_wpse_110036() {
  $count = apply_filters('limit_user_count',4);
  $users = count_reg_users_wpse_110036();
  if ($users >= $count) {
    update_option('users_can_register',0);
  }
}
add_action('user_register','limit_users_wpse_110036');

function limit_user_option_wpse_110036($option) {
  remove_filter('pre_option_users_can_register','limit_user_option_wpse_110036');
  $reg = get_option('users_can_register');
  if (0 === $reg) {
    return 0;
  }
  $count = apply_filters('limit_user_count',4);
  $users = count_reg_users_wpse_110036();
  if ($users >= $count) {
    update_option('users_can_register',0);
    return 0;
  } else {
    return $option;
  }
}
add_filter('pre_option_users_can_register','limit_user_option_wpse_110036');
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution. Only drawback: It doesn't take Network installs into account. You'd have to a `JOIN` for the `usermeta` table and then check based on `get_current_blog_id()` and `blog_id` key if the user belongs to the current site.

Comment: Yeah, network installs are a weakness. I don't use them. I'll see what I can do though. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Oh, really? Any reason why? Asking because it's the opposite for me: Using nothing than Networks even for single installs.

Comment: I deal with very small businesses who will never need a network and I deal with business owners with limited technical knowledge for the most part. I have never seen the need to enable a network. Plus, server requirements are higher for networks.

Comment: I wanted to suggest the following to get it compatible with Network installs, but found out that there's no `blog_id` in the user meta table. After taking a look at the `WP_User_Query` internals I found out that there's some pretty nasty stuff inside, so the following _might_ work... in _maybe_ 90% of all cases... and in theory :/ `$wpdb->prepare( "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} as m ON ({$wpdb->users}.ID = m.user_id) WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.%s = %s", absint( "{$wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $GLOBALS['blog_id'] )}user_level" ), $GLOBALS['blog_id'] );`